# Domain Wildcard configuration for Apache, matching middle part of FQDN

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, apache-2.4

I have a dev setup working with apache wildcards, my setup looks like the following example.

- Customer has a domain like fancy-company.org
- I own a testing.com domain, for testing / stating.
- the staging url is fancy-company.org.testing.com

in my apache config I use this configuration which works just fine.

```
    ServerAlias *.testing.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3+/public_html
```

which matches (fancy-company.org).testing.com.
now I want to include the www. subdomain in the process, since some customers are confused, if they are used to type their domain with www.

so I need a version, which matches www.(fancy-company.org).testing.com

```
    ServerAlias www.*.testing.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2-3/public_html
```

The domain www.fancy-company.org.testing.com is captured by the Virtualhost but the Documentroot is not translated to `fancy-company.org`
`%2-3` seems not to be working.

The examples at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html dont cover this case and I can't figure it out.

the VirtualDocumentRoot should match the same folder like in the previous setup: `fancy-customer.com`

Comment: I think your question could be made looking much better with only a little work. You may be interested to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original configuration, you used a negative number in the `VirtualDocumentRoot`.  This is good, because according to the documentation, a negative number counts backwards starting from the TLD, so it would match regardless of whether or not the `www` was used.

The domain `www.fancy-company.org.testing.com` would be interpreted like this:

```
-1: com
-2: testing
-3: org
-4: fancy-company
-5: www
```

The parts that are relevant to you are -3 and -4.  However, we can't use `%-4.%-3`, because a dot is interpreted as a substring.  So, our final `VirtualDocumentRoot` string should be:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-4.0.%-3.0/public_html
```

Comment: that is correct, but i want to match www.(fancy-domain.org).testing.com

Comment: @easteregg Thanks for the clarification.  I edited the answer.

Comment: perfect! thank you very much! i overlooked the %x.0 notation!